# Convert XPath to CSS

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

```
//td[@class='Bu']/following::td[@class='Bu']
```

or

```
//td[@class='Bu'][2]
```

both are the same result when using XPath, so how can I change/convert them to CSS?

Comment: td.Bu ~ td.Bu 

it worked - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this with a CSS selector if the second `td.Bu` is a following sibling (means they share the same parent), or their parents are siblings and there are only two of them:

```
td.Bu ~ td.Bu
```

If they're completely unrelated, then it's not possible with CSS.

Comment: they have a parent table that has class selector of Bs